# Trapped in npm upgrade and can't downgrade

Tags: node.js, npm

Following a Node.js/npm tutorial I ran

```
$ npm install uuid
```

and noticed the following output:

```
╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                │
│      New major version of npm available! 6.14.5 → 10.2.4       │
│   Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.2.4   │
│               Run npm install -g npm to update!                │
│                                                                │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Wanting to run my tutorial with the latest packages, so as to not get versioning issues, I did the suggested thing. I ran:

```
$ npm install -g npm
```

The output from this was:

```
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for npm@10.2.4: wanted: {"node":"^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0"} (current: {"node":"12.18.1","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.2.4

+ npm@10.2.4
added 107 packages from 29 contributors, removed 305 packages and updated 130 packages in 3.457s
```

Now when I run

```
$ npm start
```

I get

```
ERROR: npm v10.2.4 is known not to run on Node.js v12.18.1.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`.
```

I figured I made a mistake and just need to downgrade again. Posts on Stack Overflow advised me:

```
$ npm install -g npm@6.14.5
```

But this doesn't work:

```
ERROR: npm v10.2.4 is known not to run on Node.js v12.18.1. .....
```

Another post suggested:

```
$ npm install n -g
```

But same error.

So I thought I would fallback to my trusty OS package manager:

```
$ sudo apt install nodejs
```

responds with

```
nodejs is already the newest version (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.2).
```

Similar if I try to reinstall npm:

```
npm is already the newest version (8.5.1~ds-1).
```

So I am trapped in an incorrect verion of npm, and cannot downgrade back again because npm won't run, while my OS says I'm on the latest version.

- What is a canonical solution to get back to where I was?
- Do I need to reinstall npm? Do I need to reinstall nodejs?
- If both, which one first?
- What package manager or raw command should I be using?

Comment: Why are you using Node 12 at all? That's long out of support: https://nodejs.org/en/about/previous-releases. Install an up-to-date Node.js LTS version (see e.g. https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager) and it will come with a compatible npm in the box.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Why am I using Node 12 at all?   I don't know. I'm following a tutorial.  Perhaps you could recommend a better tutorial than the one I'm following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the fix I eventually traced down: Use [Volta](https://volta.sh/) to control Node JS versions.

```
$ node -v
v12.18.1
$ sudo apt purge nodejs
$ sudo snap remove node
$ volta install node@21
$ node -v
v21.3.0
```

---

**Note:**

The advise from @jonrsharpe in the comments above was to visit https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager

However the results of the instructions at that page were a package / installation error:

```
$ NODE_MAJOR=21
$ echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list 
deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_21.x nodistro main
$ sudo apt update
...
Get:7 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_21.x nodistro InRelease [12.1 kB]
Get:8 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_21.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages [1,718 B]
Fetched 243 kB in 1s (260 kB/s)     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
6 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
N: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_21.x nodistro InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
$ sudo apt install nodejs
Get:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_21.x nodistro/main amd64 nodejs amd64 21.3.0-1nodesource1 [32.3 MB]
Fetched 32.3 MB in 4s (8,678 kB/s) 
(Reading database ... 236867 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_21.3.0-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (21.3.0-1nodesource1) over (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_21.3.0-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/node/common.gypi', which is also in package libnode-dev 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.2
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_21.3.0-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```